# Only HTTPS sites are opening

Tags: wireless, networking, server, encryption, https

After updating my Ubuntu 13.10 on 14 April 2014, I am not able to access HTTP sites while HTTPS sites are working perfectly both in Firefox and Chrome. My OpenSSL is built on: Mon Apr 7 20:33:19 UTC 2014.

Even after disabling the firewall (ufw) I'm still getting the same problem.

I don't have any proxies and the connection is working properly on Windows 7. I'm using an IPv4 connection.

Running `curl -I http://www.goal.com` outputs:

```
curl: (7) Failed connect to www.goal.com:80; Connection refused
```

Running `curl -I https://www.facebook.com` outputs:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Pragma: no-cache
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
P3P: CP="Facebook does not have a P3P policy. Learn why here: http://fb.me/p3p"
Set-Cookie: reg_fb_gate=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F; path=/; domain=.facebook.com
Set-Cookie: reg_fb_ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F; path=/; domain=.facebook.com
Set-Cookie: reg_ext_ref=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.facebook.com
Set-Cookie: datr=wqRPU4Z-hF3X-hBKAETHSigT; expires=Sat, 16-Apr-2016 09:54:10 GMT; path=/; domain=.facebook.com; httponly
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-FB-Debug: 1+75zIbj9WRZIy5jpy/nhiK2naa1srTxfY5r/XeHsgk=
Date: Thu, 17 Apr 2014 09:54:10 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```